# HTTPS Proxy setup does not redirect to subdirectory

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, https

Thank you for reading :-). I have multiple applications on a server which are routed to by a proxy server. I recently added HTTPS after which the API and blog applications (at /api and /blog respectively) stopped routing.

I used [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) to setup the HTTPS configuration.

I also noticed, if I attempt to access the api/blog over HTTP with the www. domain, it works. Any idea why this might be happening?

Below is the Nginx configuration.

```
server{

    server_name mazinomedia.com;

    location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_pass http://172.31.14.107:80;
    }

    location /api/ {
        rewrite ^/api/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://172.31.14.107:10010;
    }

    location /blog/ {

        proxy_pass http://172.31.14.107:4000;
    }

    location /forum/ {

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://172.31.14.107:4567;
        proxy_redirect off;

        # Socket.IO Support
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mazinomedia.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mazinomedia.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server{
    if ($host = mazinomedia.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    if ($host = www.mazinomedia.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # Copied from certbot

    listen 80;

    server_name mazinomedia.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

I'm new to server config and have spent a few days Googleing and messing up so Many thanks in advance! ^__^

Comment: It looks like www.mazimedia.com will not work because your certifcate is valid only for mazinomedia.com?

Comment: i'm not entirely sure to be honest. Thats said, I'm attempting to access the API without www. and that doesn't work